# Use of "iff" in this statement about subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

"$H$ is a subspace of $V$ iff for all vectors $x, y \in H$, it follows that $x+y$ is also in $H$"

This is a true or false question. Now of course a necessary property of a subspace is that it is closed under addition, but it also needs to be closed under scalar multiplication and contain the zero vector. If the question was worded as "One of the requirements is closure under addition", then of course I would answer true. But does the wording in it's current state imply that closure under addition is the only condition?

Comment: It does. (Or, to be annoyingly/unnecessarily precise, the current wording states that closure under addition is a possible complete set of conditions on a subset to be a subspace.)

Comment: @MeesdeVries Hmm, "possible" complete set? In that case I guess I would have to answer false, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is false.

Consider some $x \in V$ such that $x \neq 0$, and $H = \{kx| k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. $H$ veryfies the condition on the right, but is not a subspace.

Maybe the context assumes that $H$ veryfies some other property (like closed scalar multiplication), but this sentence alone is false.